# search system from two dropdowns

Tags: php, search, mysqli, system

this is a code can someone help me with search system from 2 dropdowns and ability to sort table by Cena(price). aim lost here dont even know where to start.

Comment: I think the first thing to do is correctly define the problem. It's unclear what you are asking, and unclear what your system is supposed to do. What the input is, what the output is, how it behaves. Also, don't confuse Java and Javascript.

Comment: this is supposed to be a clasifield add website where people advertisments is sorted in table, abov the table is two dropdowns first is category dropdown (buy sell change) on change table shows only selected category(if i select  example: buy table is showing only buy results) same with other dropdown and presing on price table sorts advertisments from cheapest to most expensive.

Comment: First, don't add this as a comment. Add the description to the question. Second, this is a request for a whole system. It's not within the scope of StackOverflow. You need to make your question a bit more focused. Add to the question exactly which part didn't work, what technology you tried. Not "So many things". Things that will help us tell you "do A instead of B, you forgot to initialize C". There is no Javascript at all in your code. No attempt of your own to solve. Too broad.

Comment: well i cant put like 20 codes that didnt work i dont need a whole system at least example where or how to start

Answer (score -1, accepted):

first of all use jQuery and call change event on dropdown then inside the change event call ajax and do whatever you want to do.

Comment: ty finalay i got some progres